# Does a white noise process have constant variance by definition?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stationarity, definition, noise, white-noise

If you'll look up for the definition of a (discrete) *white noise* process on the web, you'll find some sources that say:

*"white noise is defined by zero mean, finite **and constant** variance, zero autocorrelation"*

and roughly the same amount of them that say:

*"white noise is defined by zero mean, finite variance, zero autocorrelation"*.

In the latter (e.g. [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise)), "white noise" encompasses also the case of *heteroskedastic white noise* - where the variance isn't constant. Obviously, stationarity is dropped.

Which of these two is "the" standard definition? Am I missing something?

*Note*: I submitted the same question in math.stackexchange. Whenever I get an answer, I'll delete the other one.

Answer (score 2):

There is no common definition of white noise.

You have two definitions. And there exists more definitions. For example,
white noise is a stationary stochastic process  with **constant spectral density** (and thus infinite variance).

https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/White_noise

Comment: I agree with your first phrase! Finiteness of variance was the subject of a previous question, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/278263/infinite-variance-for-a-discrete-time-white-noise-process.

Answer (score 1):

A white noise process has constant variance. So the second definition is incomplete.

Ref: Armitage encyclopedia of Biostatistics. The def there for discrete time requires that the autocorrelation looks like: $\gamma_{r,s} = \sigma \delta_{r,s}$.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's plenty of (qualified) sources that omit the constancy of variance. Someone even calls _weak white noise_ the heteroskedastic one...My opinion is that there's no consensus on the definition of "white noise", and that there's not a theorical motivation behind it.